# How to extract numbers using sed

Tags: linux, sed

How do I extract the digit(s) before last `dash(-)` and `.zip` from the following string - `fooBar-5.3.8-78642.zip` using `sed`?

I want to extract `8-78642`.

Comment: If the value is in a variable, using the shell's built-in string replacement operators would be a lot more efficient and elegant.  `head=${value%.zip}; value=${head#*[!0-9]}`

Answer (score 2):

Match the part you want with a capture group, and then replace the whole line with just that back-reference.

```
echo "fooBar-5.3.8-78642.zip" | sed -r 's/.*\.([0-9]+-[0-9]+)\.zip$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a unified and portable solution(will work on all `sed` implementations) use the following approach based on [Basic Regular Expression (BRE)](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-vs-ERE):

```
echo "fooBar-5.3.8-78642.zip" | sed 's/.*\([[:digit:]]\+\-[[:digit:]]\+\)\.zip$/\1/'
```

> Basic Regular Expression (BRE) is the default in ***sed*** (and similarly in
>   grep)

**----------------------------------------------------------------**

The second simple alternative(without regular expression) using `awk` language:

```
echo fooBar-5.3.8-78642.zip | awk -F"." '{print $3}'
```

`-F"."` - `.` here is treated as field separator

`$3` - points to the third field i.e. `8-78642`

**----------------------------------------------------------------**

And the last simple and fast alternative is using `cut` command:

```
echo "fooBar-5.3.8-78642.zip" | cut -d'.' -f3
```

---

The output(for each of the above approaches):

```
8-78642
```